# Jquery show/hide div element depending certain page element is loaded

Tags: jquery, show-hide

I would like to let Jquery detect if certain div id is loaded into the current page then hide another div id element, for example:

```
<div id="A1">some content here</div> //initially this div is visible
<div id="C1" style="display: none;">some content here</div> //initially this div is invisible
<div id="B1">some content here</div>
```

if Jquery detect the #B1 is loaded into the current page then hide #A1 and show #C1.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($("#B1").length > 0) {
  $("#A1").hide();
  $("#C1").show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function () {
    if ($('#B1').length) {
        $('#A1').hide();
        $('#C1').show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are loading the div after tyhe document loads,
so,

```
$('#B1').load('ajax/test.html', function() {
  $('#A1').hide();
  $('#C1').show();

});
```

If you're not using jQuery this would be achieved `onreadystatechanged` on the #B1 element.
other wise do it on document ready,
    $(function(){
      $('#A1").hide();
      $("#C1").show();});